# C - varying size text

Tags: c

I have to write for my assignement a program that will consist of agents and a central server deamon. It will be a distributed shell - every command issued from a server will be also performed on every agent(the output will be sent back from every agent to central server).

I will have to deal with output commands (like ls -la /home/user/dir1) - on each agent the output may vary in size). The output of "find /" will also be BIG but I have to take somehow into account that something like that can happen. What is desired way of handling varying size outputs in C and operating on them? (saving to variable, sending it over a socket).

Comment: Do you know how to handle varying size from something ridiculously simple... like a terminal?

Comment: Ff course. But I have to take care over it in C application - a proper string handling is a key to avoid problems with indexes(segfaults etc).

Answer (score 0):

The way to deal with data of arbitrary size is to use *dynamic allocation*, i.e. the functions `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`. You allocate and possibly grow the memory needed to store the command output.

Reading command output (assuming a Unix-like OS) is best done with `popen()`.
Read the manuals of each of the mentioned functions for details.

Answer (score 0):

### Dynamic Memory Allocation

To hold your "variable length" strings, you should use dynamic memory allocation: the **[malloc family](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)** of functions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *malloc(size_t size);
void free(void *ptr);
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

So, suppose you have your data stored in a variable `char *ag_str`. I suggest you `malloc` and then `realloc` the size of the buffer **in blocks**. Calling `malloc` and then `realloc` a thousand times to readjust the block size after *each character* is very costly.

So, you might do something like this:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE     4096 

struct mem_block {
    size_t current_block_size;
    size_t current_str_size;
    char *ag_str;
};

struct mem_block *new_chunk(void) 
{
    struct mem_block *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->ag_str = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    p->current_block_size = BLOCK_SIZE;
    p->current_str_size = 0;
    return p;
}

void realloc_chunk(struct mem_block *chunk)
{
    size_t ns = chunk->current_block_size + BLOCK_SIZE;
    chunk->ag_str = realloc(chunk->ag_str, ns);
    chunk->current_block_size = ns;
}

void cat_ag_str(struct mem_block *chunk, char *ag_str, size_t ag_len)
{
    if (chunk->current_str_size + ag_len > chunk->current_block_size)
        realloc_chunk(chunk);

    strncat (chunk->ag_str, ag_str, ag_len);
    chunk->current_str_size += ag_len;
}

void receive_from_agent(...)
{
    struct mem_block *chunk = new_chunk();
    ssize_t c; // Linux read/recv return
    size_t count;
    char buff[BLOCK_SIZE];

    while((c = read(your_fd, buff, BLOCK_SIZE)) // or probably recv()
        if (c < 0) ...
        count = (size_t)c;
        cat_ag_str(chunk, buff, count);

    (...)
}
```

- Note that this code **was not tested** and is just an idea for you. (*Error checking was omitted*)

  1. `struct mem_block`: This will keep information about your current memory block.
  2. `new_chunk`: function to create a new chunk handler for you.
  3. `realloc_chunk`: anytime the amount of characters that must be written exceeds the amount of characters available in the chunk, we get **one** more block.
  4. `cat_ag_str`: this will append what you just read to the memory block you have, effectively transforming chunks of data into one coherent big buffer.
  5. `receive_from_agent`: this is the entry point of your receiving loop. You may use `read` or `recv`, I don't know which you use, but both return the amount of bytes read, which you'll use to pass to `cat_ag_str`.
  6. It's important to note that you're reading in the same sized blocks as you realloc. (You can read in *smaller* chunks too, but never bigger).

You can do roughly the same for sending, but you don't need all that workaround for memory. You can just use a fixed sized buffer and copy data from your big string to it in fixed sizes, then you send the fixed-sized buffer.